Frida 16.5.9 is working on android 8.1 (redmi note 5) but not on android 13 (google pixel 6)
Iam using frida 16.5.9 and objection to bypass ssl pinning bypass for an application. What i observed is when i use frida and objection on google pixel 6 with android v.13 those are not working and iam getting various errors like “unable to spawn”, “unable to execute”, “timeout error” etc. whereas iam able to successful execute and bypass SSL pinning for the same application installed on redmi note 5 with android 8.1 version. Is anyone facing the same issue? Are there any compatibility issues for frida, objection and android version 12+? Your responses are much appreciated.
Your responses are appreciated

There are known problems: https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/2958
